# How to say "-ing" form of verbs?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

If I wanted to say "We found ourselves in traffic while driving to the airport," I would say *Ci siamo trovati nel traffico mentre guidando all'aeroporto*.

Google Translate seems to understand *guidando* as ["driving"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=it&tl=en&text=guidando) but when I enter "while driving", I get *[mentre si guida](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=it&text=while%20driving)*.

So how would a native speaker say that sentence? What is the difference between the two options and when should I use one or the other?

Comment: I'd like to stress (as implicit in the answer already given) that *_mentre guidando_ is ungrammatical: _mentre_ is only used with “finite” verbal moods: mostly indicative, rarely conditional or subjunctive, but never with gerund.

Comment: I think we should make an effort to explain the reason of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker would say:

> Ci siamo trovati nel traffico mentre **stavamo guidando** verso
>   l’aeroporto

You could replace *stavamo guidando* with a more generic *stavamo andando*  or  *andavamo* without mentioning the transportation mean.

*Mentre si guida i*s not correct here because you should use it in sentences like this:

> È vietato usare il cellulare mentre si guida
>  It is forbidden to
>   use the mobile phone while driving

Comment: In Tuscany it would be “mentre si andava all'aeroporto”.

Comment: Confermo che “guidare” come traducente di _to drive_ sa in certe frasi di calco dall'inglese, soprattutto se usato intransitivamente. In italiano diremmo “...mentre andavamo verso l'aeroporto” o, se è importante come, “...mentre andavamo in macchina verso l'aeroporto”.

Answer (score 0):

Using *"mentre si guida"* or *"guidando"* is the same, because both are referring to a **generic** situation usually done by someone, and don't specify who is driving in particular.
So for a correct translation on Google Translate I suppose you should write:

> English: "We found ourselves in traffic while *we were* driving to the airport"
>
> Italian: "Ci siamo trovati nel traffico mentre *stavamo* guidando verso l'aeroporto"

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @John! This site is about Italian language and the OP is in fact asking how to express this idea in Italian.

Comment: I'm confused: in order to explain a feature of Italian grammar you suggest a way to rephrase an English sentence before feeding it to Google Translate? Am I correct?

Comment: I'm explaining where (and why) Google Translate fails. The rephrased english sentence I wrote doesn't change the meaning of the original sentence. Does it?